# Using substr_replace and str_replace to retrieve date and time in a specific format from an input to be inserted into the db

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

When I retrieve weather results from a website, the date and time will be in a string. For eg, "date": "Thu, 16 Jun 2016 09:00 AM SGT"

I want to extract the

1. **time** (09:00) so that it can be inserted into the db in the TIME() format (hh:mm:ss)
2. **date** (Thu, 16 jun, 2016) so that it can be converted into yyyy-mm-dd before inserting into the db. I do not need the day at all.

   **//connect to mysql db**

   $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","admin","password") or die('Could not     connect: ' . mysql_error());

   **//connect to the weather database**

   mysql_select_db("weather", $con);

   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
   //date.timezone = "ETC//GMT-8"

   **//read the json file contents**

   $jsondata = file_get_contents('weather.json');

   **//convert json object to php associative array**

   $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

here are my codes to identify the day:

```
$day=array();
$day[0]="mon";
$day[1]="tue";
$day[2]="wed";
$day[3]="thurs";
$day[4]="fri";
$day[5]="sat";
$day[6]="sun";
```

//retrieve out the date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd

```
$date = $data['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']['date'];
$newdatefront = str_replace($day, '', $date);
$newdateback = substr_replace($newdatefront, '', 12,30);
$dateformat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $newdateback)));
```

//retrieving the time (09:00) to be inserted into the db

```
$time = $data['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']['date'];
$newtimefront = substr_replace($date,'',0,17);
$newtimeback = str_replace(' SGT','',$newtimefront);
$timeformat = str_replace('AM','',$newtimeback);
```

weather.json (where the results is after extracting form the website)

```
{

    "query": {
    "count": 1, 
    "created": "2016-06-16T02:07:59Z", 
    "lang": "en-US", 
    "results": {
        "channel": {
            "item": {
                "condition": {
                    "code": "4", 
                    "date": "Thu, 16 Jun 2016 09:00 AM SGT", 
                    "temp": "81", 
                    "text": "Thunderstorms"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

However, when I tried to run the codes, it prompts me *"Error: Incorrect time value: '09:00 AM' for column 'time' at row 1*

Time is the the name of the column in my database and so far I have only 1 record.

Comment: why `substr_replace` and `str_replace`???  use DateTime and Format to get converted split date and time.

Comment: If you have PHP 5.3+ (which you should) read how to use `DateTime::createFromFormat` here https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the timezone and use strtotime and date.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");
$str = 'Thu, 16 Jun 2016 09:00 AM SGT';

echo date("h:i", strtotime($str)); //09:00
echo '<br/>';
echo date("D, d M, Y", strtotime($str)); //Thu, 16 jun, 2016
```

**Update:**

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");
$date = $data['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']['date'];//Thu, 16 Jun 2016 09:00 AM SGT
echo $NewTime = date("h:i", strtotime($date )); //09:00
echo $NewDate = date("D, d M, Y", strtotime($date )); //Thu, 16 jun, 2016
```

This may help you. Let me know.

Comment: $date = $data['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']['date'];
 $Newdate=("h:i", strtotime($date));
  
 $time = $data['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']['date'];
 $Newtime = date("D, d M, Y", strtotime($time));

I have added but it prompt an error saying that there is an unexpected ,   in " $Newdate=("h:i", strtotime($date));"

Comment: you miss to use the `date(..)` when retrieving the `$Newdate`.

Comment: i dont get you sorry :x

Comment: `$Newdate=("h:i", strtotime($date));` should be `$Newdate = date("h:i", strtotime($date));`

Comment: i realized i put the codes wrongly:
$date = $data['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']['date'];
$NewDate = date("d M, Y", strtotime($date));

$time = $data['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']['date'];
$NewTime = date("h:i", strtotime($time));

Comment: You have to check and let me know.

Comment: [16-Jun-2016 16:01:56] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Newtime in C:\scripts\weather_connect.php on line 45 << im not sure what this means :/

Comment: Check my answer again and look for the **Update**.

Comment: this is what i get when i run the file on localhost " 07:30Thu, 01 Jan, 1970"

Comment: @plzhelp, Listen if your `$date` variable has date like `Thu, 16 Jun 2016 09:00 AM SGT` than you must get `09:00` as time and `Thu, 16 jun, 2016` as date.